# Positioning a circle underneath text in CSS

Tags: html, css, shapes

I'm trying to position a 5px x 5px circle in the centre of the underneath of the links in a nav to indicate which page the user is currently on, but I'm not sure how I should be going about this.

Currently I have this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PVNq.png)

I am trying to do this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZm7T.png)

This is the code:

```
        <ul id="nav-menu">
            <li class="nav-menu-item">
                <a href="ourwork.html">Our work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu-item">
                <a href="#whatwedo">What we do</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu-item">
                <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu-item">
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
  nav {
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 75px;
}
#nav-logo-link {
    flex: 1;
}
#nav-logo {
    height: 35px;
}
#nav-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav-menu > li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
#nav-menu > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

I have tried putting an `<i>` element within the `<li>` and then positioning it as absolute, and whilst I can put it down at the correct height (since the nav height is static), when I set it as `left: 0;`, it jumps to the left hand side of the entire nav. I tried putting a `<div>` within the `<li>` but that didn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an after pseudo element to do this along with a UTF8 character, see the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y34zk1h6/).

**Edit**: I'm assuming you want this to happen when the user clicks a link and is then on that page hence why I've used a data attribute, the previous answer does it on hover.

I've made three amendments to your code here:

1. Added position: relative; to your anchors, this allows me to use position: absolute in the next css block:

   ## nav-menu > li > a {

   ```
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000;
   position: relative;
   ```

   }
2. Added the pseudo element absolutely positioned at 50% of the anchor width, I've also set it's width and then centred it within that by using a negative margin of half its width. This relies on you setting the selected item with a little bit of javascript, see point 3. You may want to adjust the colour:

   ## nav-menu > li > a[data-selected=true]:after {

   ```
   content: "\25CF";
   position: absolute;
   top: 1.1em;
   left: 50%;
   width: 10px;
   margin-left: -5px;
   color: cadetblue;
   ```

   }
3. Added a data-selected="true" attribute to the selected anchor, you need to do this in javascript as a different anchor is selected. This allows the css in step 2 to select the right anchor.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.

Comment: Good stuff, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding a `nav-menu-item:after{` rule which adds a circle after the `<li>` tag then set the display for the `#nav-menu > li {` to inline-block and you should get the desired result on hover

```css
nav {
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 75px;
}

#nav-logo-link {
  flex: 1;
}

#nav-logo {
  height: 35px;
}

#nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#nav-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#nav-menu > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.nav-menu-item:hover:after {
  content: "\25CF";
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.nav-menu-item::after {
  content: "\25CF";
  opacity: 0;
  color: #1ba9b3;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="nav-menu">
    <li class="nav-menu-item">
      <a href="ourwork.html">Our work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-menu-item">
      <a href="#whatwedo">What we do</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-menu-item">
      <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-menu-item">
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you want to show the dot when selected you can use javascript to set the class to be `<li class="nav-menu-item selected">` then in css you would change `.nav-menu-item:hover:after {` to `.nav-menu-item.selected:after {`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!